# Need help in regular expression using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have following code:-

```
test -z "$(echo ${JIRA_DETAIL} | jq '.fields.status.name' | sed -r "s/\"(Done|Completed|Closed)\"//")" && echo "Found valid Jira" || echo "Not a valid Jira (Closed/Completed/Done)"
```

The code works. When the status is one of the among **(done, completed or closed)** then it prints **"Found valid Jira"**. I want the `"Not In"` condition of it i.e. whenever the status comes out to be any of these then it should say **"Found valid Jira"**.

Jira details response that I get is as follows:-

```
{
   "expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
   "id":"10000",
   "self":"https://mycloudbox.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/10000",
   "key":"MYC-1",
   "fields":{
      "status":{
         "self":"https://mycloudbox.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/status/3",
         "description":"This issue is being actively worked on at the moment by the assignee.",
         "iconUrl":"https://mycloudbox.atlassian.net/images/icons/statuses/inprogress.png",
         "name":"In Progress",
         "id":"3",
         "statusCategory":{
            "self":"https://mycloudbox.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/statuscategory/4",
            "id":4,
            "key":"indeterminate",
            "colorName":"yellow",
            "name":"In Progress"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I tried going through with docs but it is confusing. I'm not good in regex hence checking. How to put ^ or Not In condition on this?

**[Updated defective Code using Linux If-Else]**
It is going every time in else condition and printing **Valid JIRA Id found!**. Pls suggest as I want to try out using Linux If-Else only, thanks

```
- |
      if [[ "$JIRA_STATUS" == "^(Done|Completed|Closed)$" ]] 
       then 
         echo "Invalid JIRA (Done/Completed/Closed) found!"
         exit 1
       else echo "Valid JIRA Id found!" 
      fi
```

Comment: This can probably be done in JQ itself, please [edit] ypur question to show the in put JSON!

Comment: I do not want to use JQ here. Can you please guide me using linux shell if-else command. Here is my code so far and everytime it is going in else condition only and printing "Valid JIRA Id found!" - |
      if [[ "$JIRA_STATUS" == "^(Done|Completed|Closed)$" ]] 
       then 
         echo "Invalid JIRA (Done/Completed/Closed) found!"
         exit 1
       else echo "Valid JIRA Id found!" 
      fi

Comment: "I do not want to use jq"?  Your pipeline already includes jq, and the question's tags include `jq`.  If you just want sed enlightenment, then perhaps it would avoid confusion if you simply removed the jq tag?

Comment: sorry about that. I have removed jq tag

Comment: @vinod827, can there be more than 1 `status` field in your file? If yes then please edit your samples, thank you.

Comment: No, only these 3 I'm expecting

Comment: @vinod827, No I meant will there be more than 1 status columns? Like 1 will have `Done` and other will have `Work in progress` and so on? OR there will be always 1 status only in whole file?

Comment: One status attribute in the whole file. That API response is coming from the JIRA server only. I'm looking to put a check around only for 3 statuses (Closed, Done, Completed) that may come depending upon the life cycle of a ticket but at any given time, it will be only 1 value to the status attribute like Open, Done, Closed, Completed, Blocked, Work In Progress, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for guiding me.

I'm finally able to resolve this issue by modifying the code like below:-

```
- |
      if test -z "$(echo ${JIRA_STATUS} | sed -r "s/\"(Done|Completed|Closed)\"//")" 
        then 
          echo "Not a valid Jira (Done/Completed/Closed)"; exit 1
        else 
          echo "Valid Jira found!"; echo $?
      fi
```

I had used the test command along with if-else condition in Linux to make it work

Comment: Thanks for sharing Vinod. But In my humble opinion this is having flaws(though no take away from your efforts to achieve this, keep it up). Problem here is: you are simply checking `Done|Completed|Closed`  which is **assuming** that only `status` line will have this, imagine if any other line contains this then it will be problematic, so IMHO you can also try mine and all other non-jq solutions once and let respective people know about how their solutions went, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Also just in case you are not aware, to thank people in Stack Overflow you can up-vote their answers and accept anyone of the answer also out of all helpful answer, cheers.

Comment: I am confused for several reasons: What does this answer include that existing answers don't? Where does "$JIRA_STATUS" come from and why does it contain a quoted value? If you are extracting the status with `jq` (as is done in the first snippet of the Q), then why not use `-r`/`--raw-output` to get the string value without quotes? Why complicate things with `test -z`, command substitution and sed with extended regex, when a simple `case` statement would suffice? I think this is the solution in this answer is more complicated than any other answer here.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (.fields.status.name | IN("done", "completed", "closed")) 
    then "Found valid Jira" 
    else "Found INVALID Jira" 
end
```

Will output `Found valid Jira` if the `.field.status.name` is found in one of the params passed to [`IN()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#in), otherwise, print `Found INVALID Jira`

#### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FabYRLJIV4l)

---

Note that `IN()` is **case-sensitive**, use `ascii_downcase` to convert the name to lowercase, to simplify the cases:

```
if (.fields.status.name | ascii_downcase | IN("done", "completed", "closed")) 
    then "Found valid Jira" 
    else "Found INVALID Jira" 
end
```

Comment: You might need to verify if the names start with upper case letters, if not `IN` would not match it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do this with jq directly?

```
if .fields.status.name | IN("Done","Completed","Closed")
then "Found valid Jira"
else "Not a valid Jira (Closed/Completed/Done)"
end
```

Complete example:

```
printf '%s' "$JIRA_DETAIL" | jq -r 'if .fields.status.name | IN("Done","Completed","Closed")
then "Found valid Jira"
else "Not a valid Jira (Closed/Completed/Done)"
end'
```

Or shorter, but more obscure:

```
(.fields.status.name | select(IN("Done","Completed","Closed")) | "Found valid Jira")
// "Not a valid Jira (Closed/Completed/Done)"
```

```
{
    true: "Found valid Jira",
    false: "Not a valid Jira (Closed/Completed/Done)"
}[.fields.status.name | IN("Done","Completed","Closed") | tostring]
```

Another option is to have a map from your status names to outputs (more flexible, but for this simple case it uses quite a lot of repetition):

```
{
    Done: "Found valid Jira",
    Completed: "Found valid Jira",
    Closed: "Found valid Jira"
}[.fields.status.name] // "Not a valid Jira (Closed/Completed/Done)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since OP don't want to use `jq` so coming up with GNU `awk` solution here. With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk` code. Written and tested with in GNU `awk`.

```bash
awk -v RS='\n[[:space:]]+"status":{([^\n]*\n[[:space:]]+)*"name":[^,]*,' '
RT{
   split(RT,arr,"\"name\":")
   gsub(/"|,$/,"",arr[2])
   value=arr[2]
   if(value=="Done" || value=="Completed" || value=="Closed"){ exit } 
   else{ print "Valid JIRA Id found!" }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: "can't use jq" is interesting, because the question already contains `jq` to extract the status name. I think the problem is more that OP does not _want_ to use `jq` when generating the output (for whatever reason)

Comment: @knittl, ok sure. I have corrected statement now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a second answer, because the question has taken a 180° turn. I will still leave my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74097347/112968) alone, in case anybody is looking for a solution for the initial problem.

---

If all you want to do is invert the "true" and "false" branches of an `if` statement, simply swap the branches or negate the condition:

```
if condition; then 
  : true branch (1)
else
  : false branch (2)
fi
```

Becomes either

```
if condition; then 
  : false branch (2) # swapped with (1)
else
  : true branch (1) # swapped with (2)
fi
```

or

```
if ! condition; then 
  : false branch (2)
else
  : true branch (1)
fi
```

But the foremost problem is your usage of the regex. `==` is the string comparison operator and does not match against a regex. So your condition is *always* false (unless `JIRA_STATUS` is actually defined/assigned as `JIRA_STATUS='^(Done|Completed|Closed$)'`).

So you must change the operator to match against a regex, i.e. use `=~`, and then use a regex and not a string, i.e. `^(…)$` not `"^(…)$"` (*unquoted!*):

```
if ! [[ "$JIRA_STATUS" =~ ^(Done|Completed|Closed)\$ ]]; then 
  echo "Invalid JIRA (Done/Completed/Closed) found!"
  exit 1
else
  echo "Valid JIRA Id found!" 
fi
```

without negating the result, the branches can be switched:

```
if [[ "$JIRA_STATUS" =~ ^(Done|Completed|Closed)\$ ]]; then 
  echo "Valid JIRA Id found!" 
else
  echo "Invalid JIRA (Done/Completed/Closed) found!"
  exit 1
fi
```

Having to escape certain characters on the LHS of the regex matching operator is annoying, so you can extract a variable and then expand this variable *without* quotes on the LHS:

```
valid_statuses='^(Done|Completed|Closed)$'
if [[ "$JIRA_STATUS" =~ $valid_statuses ]]; then 
  echo "Valid JIRA Id found!" 
else
  echo "Invalid JIRA (Done/Completed/Closed) found!"
  exit 1
fi
```

Simple alternatives can not only be encoded as regex alternatives, but as boolean conditions:

Since you are comparing against fixed strings, I'd like to suggest a simpler solution using a `case` statement, it easier to write and read, plus it is POSIX compatible (i.e. can be used in other shells, not only bash):

```
case "$JIRA_STATUS" in
  Done|Completed|Closed) echo 'Valid JIRA ID found!' ;;
  *) echo 'Invalid JIRA (Done/Completed/Closed) found!'
     exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Chaining multiple conditions (valid statuses) is also possible with `||` in the if statement, but I find the `case` solution easier to read and extend:

```
if [[ "$JIRA_STATUS" = 'Done' ]]
|| [[ "$JIRA_STATUS" = 'Completed' ]]
|| [[ "$JIRA_STATUS" = 'Closed' ]]; then 
  echo "Valid JIRA Id found!" 
else
  echo "Invalid JIRA (Done/Completed/Closed) found!"
  exit 1
fi
```